# Save .sav file as excel with variable descriptions in R

Tags: r

I have a .sav file where the variables have descriptions (they show up as smaller text under variable names on the console in R). Is there a way to save the variable names, descriptions and data in an excel file?
If not, can I extract a list of variable name and corresponding descriptions, and save it in any format?

Comment: Well probably, but the question is too broad. You need to demonstrate that you have investigated how to perform some of the obvious intermediate steps and show where you are getting stuck. SO is not a do-my-project-for-me sort of venue.

Comment: .sav is an SPSS data file format, right?  Use `foreign::read.spss()` [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.spss.html) or `haven::read_spss()` [link](https://haven.tidyverse.org/).

Comment: Here's also some useful information on how to work with labels and potentially extract them. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/06/working-with-spss-labels-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse` extracting the labels and variable names to CSV would be:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- read_sav("data_file_with_labels.sav")
data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) attributes(x)$label)) %>% 
  gather() %>%
  write_csv("variables.csv")
```